# XCode does not open at all on Mac Mini

Tags: xcode, macos

I bought an M1 Mac Mini recently and tried to use XCode on it, but it does not open at all.

I tried re-install it and delete ~/Library/Developer directory, it seems nothing works.

This is my first Mac device and if I give more detail about what I mean by 'does not open at all' - it does nothing even if I double click the XCode from Applications directory or the bar at the bottom that has other installed applications showing on it(sorry, I don't know how this is called).

I can see the little grey dot under the icon which means it is running somehow, but nothing comes up on the screen. Then the grey dot goes away after few minutes with nothing happening.

How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: Bar at the bottom is called the "dock"

Comment: Did you unarchive the xip file? Or did you Xcode from the App Store?

Comment: @matt Got it from App Store

Answer (score 2):

Making sure that the application itself is in the right place would be my first approach. Did you download Xcode from the App Store?

Here’s a link to someone with the same issue asking on the Apple developers forum

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/101265

Comment: Yes, I got it from the App Store. I will check the link, thank you

Comment: This did not resolve the issue... but thanks.

Comment: From within the Applications folder, right click on the XCode icon and select Show Package Contents>Contents>MacOS> Launch the Unix Executable File found in this directory: see what you get.

Comment: ```objc[1196]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1f6dc5160) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x1211c42b8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.``` It's what I am getting.

Comment: And 2 more lines: ```2021-06-01 23:55:57.532 Xcode[1196:20398] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost``` and ```2021-06-01 23:55:57.532 Xcode[1196:20398] nil host used in call to allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:```

Comment: DO THE FOLLOWING: Find it by opening a finder window alt+command+space bar then click on your main hard drive icon, follow the path: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x1211c42b8). Duplicate it (right click on it and duplicate option shows) and put the copy somewhere safe (Desktop is fine). Right-click on the original and "move to trash". Launch XCode again. Still more stuff we can do after that, so provide status upon completion if more help is needed.

Comment: I think it's a bit different on my computer, I could copy and paste the file into Desktop which is equivalent to duplicate (there was no duplicate option when I right click on it) and I can't move the original file to the bin. No such an option and drag and drop does not work either.

Comment: 1.Try to do it to its parent dirctory 2.Check the files permission (rightclick>info>padlocks towards the botom) and or 3.Start the machine in and try the again: **Start up an Intel-based Mac in safe mode
On your Mac, choose Apple menu  > Shut Down.
After your Mac shuts down, wait 10 seconds.
Restart your Mac, then immediately press and hold the Shift key.
Release the Shift key when you see the login window.**

Comment: [safe mode](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/start-up-your-mac-in-safe-mode-mh21245/mac)

Answer (score 0):

Go to applications folder, right click, "get info" and then “Open using Rosetta”. Check the box.